# Can't install Ubuntu on Asus Eee 1015pem

Tags: installation, hardware, asus

I'm having trouble to install Ubuntu. I use an ASUS Eee 1015pem netbook. Recently, my netbook got wet. I had it inside my backback and all my things got wet. The netbook boots up fine but it will not load the OS. I downloaded Ubuntu onto my external hard drive and changed the settings in my BIOS to boot from a removable device. Nothing happens. When I plug in my external hard drive I'm not able to get to the boot icon. I have to unplug the external hard drive. For my boot settings I tried both Removable and CD-Rom. Then I plugged my external drive back in and nothing happened with either setting. My Asus never came with a recovery disk--it's suppose to have a build in recovery utility accessed by pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> in the BIOS.  Also I need to disable Boot Booster in the BIOS and Boot Booster is not even an opition in the BIOS. My friend told me to try installing Ubuntu but now I'm having no luck with Ubuntu. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my asus eee pc 1215t. I rebooted windows 7 twice, but did not work. So i did some googling and found the same thing as you and my bios is v02.61 americanmegatrends. It does not have boot booster.

Then I found a better way for you to recover your PC. Do not install the same operating system but run the installation for Windows XP.

1. Buy or download Windows XP.
2. Do not install it but run through the setup.
3. While running windows xp setup format all partitions.
4. After formatting all partitions through Windows XP, you must cancel the intallation or shut down your pc as soon you clean all partitions.
5. Now your hard drive is clean, try to install linux ubuntu 6 when finish installing linux, do not forget to update your BIOS through the BIO website.

Comment: Why would this be better than booting from an Ubuntu live CD/DVD or USB flash drive and creating a partition table in GParted (which will also result in a hard drive with no data-containing partitions on it)? I'm asking because if this solution is not really specific to the Windows CD, then given the useful information you've provided, someone can make an answer, or edit your answer, to explain how to accomplish the same thing with an Ubuntu live CD/DVD or live USB flash drive instead. For many people, an Ubuntu live CD/DVD or USB flash drive is more readily available than a Windows disc.